# Is there any way to merge fields without adding the doneMatch into the field?

Tags: azure-devops-extensions, azure-devops-migration-tools

We need to merge two fields into one.  In the config, there is a "doneMatch" special string, and this seems to get appended to the merged field.  Why is this needed, and is there a way to not have it also appended to the target field?

For example, I have: 
src.fieldA = "City" 
src.fieldB = "State"

I want to merge these 2 fields into target.fieldA as "City: State".  However, what I end up with is "City: State##DONE##"  I can change the config file so that it uses a different doneMatch but it can't be null or empty.. so if I changed it to ";", then the resulting field would be "City: State;".  I have to have an end done char/string for some reason.  What is this used for? If I am synching the fields with newer updates, is it going to detect the previous ##DONE## in the target.fieldA and think it's already done the merge, so would not make any new changes?

Can someone send me more info on this feature?

Comment: Sorry, I should have feedback in about a week or less.

Comment: It's ok. I will wait for your feedback. Feel free to let me know the progress. If you still have problem, I could also give you some help.

Comment: unfortunately, it is literally taking the "&nbsp" as a string, and appends that to the field.

Comment: Hi @Sclieu Yu. I tested it again and the answer could only work on the `Text (multiple lines)` field. Please check the update. You could create a new field  and set it as target field.

Comment: This may need a code change. I am not sure why the doneMatch is required and would need to have a look at the code.

Comment: OK, I just checked it out and the doneMatch is a poor way to test for the merge already having taken place.... I'm looking into it.

Comment: Unfortunately, we can not verify the changes any time soon, but I will accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated the code for v9.0.1 that changes the way that the FieldMerge works. It no longer uses doneMatch and instead requires that all 3 fields are different and then skips if it has already been done.

```
 if (source.Fields.Contains(config.sourceField1) && source.Fields.Contains(config.sourceField2))
            {
                var val1 = source.Fields[config.sourceField1].Value != null ? source.Fields[config.sourceField1].Value.ToString() : string.Empty;
                var val2 = source.Fields[config.sourceField2].Value != null ? source.Fields[config.sourceField2].Value.ToString() : string.Empty;
                var valT = target.Fields[config.targetField].Value != null ? target.Fields[config.targetField].Value.ToString() : string.Empty;
                var newValT = string.Format(config.formatExpression, val1, val2);

                if (valT.Equals(newValT))
                {
                    Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("  [SKIP] field already merged {0}:{1}+{2} to {3}:{4}", source.Id, config.sourceField1, config.sourceField2, target.Id, config.targetField));
                } else
                {
                    target.Fields[config.targetField].Value = string.Format(config.formatExpression, val1, val2) + config.doneMatch;
                    Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("  [UPDATE] field merged {0}:{1}+{2} to {3}:{4}", source.Id, config.sourceField1, config.sourceField2, target.Id, config.targetField));
                }

            }
```

https://github.com/nkdAgility/azure-devops-migration-tools/pull/529

Answer (score 0):

Test the field merge with Azure Devops Migration tools, I could also reproduce this situation. The `doneMatch` field is required in the `configuration.json` file(##Done## by default).

There seems to be no way to avoid adding `donematch` to the target field. Since I am not the developer of this tool, I am not sure about the function of this field.

I would like to share a workaround to solve this issue.

**Workaround:**

You could try to set the `"&nbsp;"` to the `doneMatch` field. ( `"doneMatch": "&nbsp;"`)

For example:

```
 "FieldMaps": [
    {
      "ObjectType": "VstsSyncMigrator.Engine.Configuration.FieldMap.FieldMergeMapConfig",
      "WorkItemTypeName": "*",
      "sourceField1": "System.Description",
      "sourceField2": "Microsoft.VSTS.Common.AcceptanceCriteria",
      "targetField": "System.Description",
      "formatExpression": "{0} {1}",
      "doneMatch": "&nbsp;"
    }
```

Since the configuration file is a Json file, you could use `"&nbsp;"` to represent spaces.

Result:

[image]

> is it going to detect the previous ##DONE## in the target.fieldA and
> think it's already done the merge, so would not make any new changes

Based on my test, the `##Done##` in the target field will not affect other operations. You can still operate on this field.

**Update:**

The above method could only work on  field type: `Text (multiple lines)`. If the field is other types, this method doesn't work.

You could create a new field(`Text (multiple lines)`). Then you could set the target field as the new field.

e.g.

```
 "FieldMaps": [

 
    {
      "ObjectType": "VstsSyncMigrator.Engine.Configuration.FieldMap.FieldMergeMapConfig",
      "WorkItemTypeName": "*",
      "sourceField1": "Custom.test1",
      "sourceField2": "Custom.test2",
      "targetField": "Custom.test3",
      "formatExpression": "{0} {1}",
      "doneMatch": "&nbsp;"
    }
```